# stuck on not being able to view contents of an array list

Tags: java, arrays, get

I'm very new to java and finding it hard to get used to the terms, I have searched the internet but everything I try doesn't work because I dont know how to properly implement it into my code... how can I simply get the console to display what I have entered into the array list? thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Account {
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> address = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> createOption = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> sortCode = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> deposit = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> accountNumber = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void accountCreation() {
        String name = "", address = "", createOption = "", sortCode = "", deposit = "";
        double accountNumber = 0;
        boolean valid = false;
        while (!valid) {
            System.out.println("What account would you like to create?");
            System.out.println("Current or savings?");
            createOption = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (createOption.equalsIgnoreCase("current") || createOption.equalsIgnoreCase("savings")) {
                valid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter checking or savings");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Please enter your name:");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter your address");
        address = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter an initial deposit");
        deposit = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter an sort code ");
        sortCode = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter an account number");
        accountNumber = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        valid = false;

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: iterate over the list and print the contents, how else?

Comment: @Stultuske Before that putting the values into those lists :)

Comment: As a sidenote, judging your `List`'s i suspect that you should create a class with 6 instance variables and only hold only a `List` of this class.

Comment: But before you ask that, why do you have lists of names, addresses, and so on? The class is `Account`; you need a single representation of each of these and a `List<Account>`.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ not unimportant, but the question is: how do I print what I have entered? :)

Comment: @Stultuske Fair point. #facepalm ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it incorrectly. You'll have to use `add()` to add an item to the `ArrayList`.

For Example:

```
name.add(keyboard.nextLine());
```

In order to display the items in the `ArrayList` you can use a loop as follows:

```
for(String n : name) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + n);
}
```

You'll have to correct it for all other `ArrayLists` in your program.

Comment: This gives an error "the method add(string) is undefined for the type string

Comment: Okay I was typing it wrong aha, onto the display part, what is the for(string name : names) bit? there is an error under 'names' (names cannot be resolved to a variable)

Comment: `names` should be the name of your ArrayList. I just realized that it is `name` and not `names`. You can check the updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your complete for the case of the name because your code cannot print anything as the **main** method is missing:

```
public class Account {
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new Account().accountCreation();
}

List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

public void accountCreation() {

    final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter your name:");
    names.add(keyboard.nextLine());
    for (final String name : names) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }
}
```

}

You can do the rest in a similar fashion. (ArrayList makes sense only if you want to have a lot entries; in case you need that you should loop.) ....

Comment: my reputation scores are reduced by 20 points for this answer? what is wrong? At least it is fair to give a reason why.

Comment: I don't see any rep reduction due to this post (or anywhere). You can view your rep [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5910091/ujulu?tab=reputation). Maybe a couple people changed their mind on an up-vote and you returned to your original rep.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks for the information. I am relatively new here and don't apprehend what has happened except that I had 20 points less. So I thought I might have done something against the rules of the usage.